# Firebase sync new users with airtable

Tags: firebase, airtable

I have a user list in Airtable and user accounts on FireBase.
I want to create a new record on Airtable every time a new user signs up to firebase (the list under authentication).

Is there a way to strictly automate that process from within those 2 platforms / using Zapier?

Answer (score 1):

At this time the only triggers available for Firebase in Zapier are:

- New Child Object in a Firebase Realtime Database
- New Document Within a Firestore Collection

For confirmation see https://zapier.com/apps/firebase/integrations/airtable.

This means in order to automatically create a new record on Airtable every time a new user signs up to Firebase, you'd need to have some process before Firebase (i.e. in your front-end user sign-up sequence) that not only creates a new Firebase User but simultaneously creates an object in Firebase Realtime Database (or Firestore) representing that User. So that (in Firebase Console) the User appears not only under Authentication but also under Database.

If you're able to configure that initial process then Zapier will be able to deliver what you need. Let me know how you get on; if I get a chance to update this answer with some example code I'll do that.